# Reuse common components between a ReactJS and a React Native application via a design system

Tags: reactjs, react-native, storybook

I have two separate applications: one React web application and one React Native application (currently targeting iOS and Android). Both applications serve different purposes but they should both adhere to the same style and design.

Is there a way to extract a library of common React components (form fields, buttons, icons, labels, widgets, etc.) and import these in the two applications?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, look `yarn workspace` this is what you need.

This is also called a Monorepo (https://medium.com/@ratebseirawan/react-native-0-63-monorepo-walkthrough-36ea27d95e26)

Hope this can help you!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. A monorepo with workspaces does help with code sharing in general. However, it doesn't answer if it is possible to import a React component into a React Native project (for example a form field component with a label and an input text). 
Does it have to be implemented individually on each application and they can share a common theme or can the two applications actually share the same component?

Comment: No, you can not share component that are react specific or react native specific. You can only share typescript objects such as `interface` `custom object` or a `theme` or `constant` file...